# How to read operator . function type

Tags: haskell

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g = \x -> f(g x)
```

I don't quite understand how to read the function type.

- `(b -> c)` is a function takes an argument b, returns c, i assume this is function f
- `(a -> b)` is a function takes an argument a, return b, i assume this is function g

not sure how are c in (b -> **c**) and a in (**a** -> b) are relate to **a** -> **c**

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's better to parenthesise a bit more,

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

and read it:

`(.)` takes two arguments,

- one function (`f`) of type `b -> c`
- one function (`g`) of type `a -> b`

and returns a function (`f . g`) of type `a -> c`.

The argument type `a` of the resulting function is the type of the argument of `(.)`'s second argument (`g`, which is first applied to the argument of `f . g`), and the result type of the composition is the result type of `(.)`'s first argument (`f`, which is then applied to the result of the application of `g` to the argument).